# Run JavaScript from PHP from Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Is it possible to run a JavaScript function from PHP using an Ajax call.

For example, if I have a html page in php with an ajax call. The ajax post gets sent to a php engine:

**index.php**

```
<script>
  Ajax.post('http://example.com/ajaxEngine.php', { data: "someData" });
</script>
```

Then in the PHP engine, can I run a JavaScript function like this:

**ajaxEngine.php**

```
<?php

$data = $_POST['data'];

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var php_var = "<?php echo data ?>";
   function doSomething(php_var) {
   // do something with data 
   }
</script>
```

Lastly, If the JavaScript function needs to return a value, how would you then transfer that back to php? Could I post to the same page and then get it as a variable with PHP?

Comment: *Why* do you need that? Why can't you `doSomething` *before* sending the AJAX request?

Comment: Did Not make any `sense`

Comment: Because I want to hide the script.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

Your code in ajaxEngine.php would just output that snippet of javascript. This will be transfered back to your page, so you could insert it into a script tag or eval it, if you like it to execute. But this would then happen on the client side not on your server. The script would have the dynamic data from the php, though. So if this is everything you need, it would work that way.

Beware: That would NOT hide your script. It would be visible for any client.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
function includetext(text,onlyone)
{
    var d=document.createElement('script');
    if(onlyone)
    {
        var ds=document.getElementById('onlyonesscript');
        if(ds)
            removeElement(ds);
        d.id='onlyonesscript';
    }
    d.innerHTML=text;
    document.body.appendChild(d);
}
```

`text` - returing text of script from ajax.

`onlyone` use for just one script node, this will help you.

**ajaxEngine.php**

```
<?php

$data = $_POST['data'];

?>
var php_var = "<?php echo data ?>";
// do something with data
```